# ALE - how to configure warnings to appear in the command line?

Tags: plugin-ale

I'm trying to workout whether this is an issue with my ALE configuration, or it's some kind of bug with the linter.

Basically I'm using `tsserver` and `prettier` for Typescript with ALE. Both error and warning signs are appearing as expected in the gutter.

When I put the cursor over an error, I see the error in the command line.

But when I put the cursor over a warning, nothing is showing in the command line.

Is this normal behaviour, and if so is it possible to configure that?  Or am I experiencing some kind of issue?

I can actually see the warning messages if I use the `:lopen` command, but I'd like to see them when moving the cursor over them too.

Additional info:

```
NVIM v0.3.2
Build type: Release
```

Comment: I assume by status line you actually mean command-line (area you type in after `:`)? The status line typically denotes the line configured by the `statusline` option.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, yes you're right. I meant the command-line.